# How to manage GraphQL child objectType that can be nullable in an output type?

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm setting up a nodeJS GraphQL API and I'm experimenting a blocking point regarding one of my resource output type.

The feature is a form that contain three different level :

- Level 1- formTemplate
- Level 2- formItems (templateId, type (video, image, question) - 1-N relation with formTemplate)
- Level 3- formQuestions (0-1 relation with formItem if and only if formItems.type is 'question')

My GraphQL resource is returning all the templates in the database so it's an array that for each template is returning all his items and each item of type "question" needs to return an array containing the associated question.

My problem is : I really don't know how to return an empty object type for the formItems where type is different from "question" or if there is a better approach for this kind of situation

I've tried to look at GraphQL directives and inline fragments but I think it really needs to be manage by the backend side because it's transparent for the API consumer.

```
const formTemplate = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FormTemplate',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      authorId: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      name: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
      },
      items: {
        type: new GraphQLList(formItem),
        resolve: parent => FormItem.findAllByTemplateId(parent.id)
      }
    }
  }
})

const formItem = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FormItem',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      templateId: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      type: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
      },
      question: {
        type: formQuestion,
        resolve: async parent => FormQuestion.findByItemId(parent.id)
      }
    }
  }
})

const formQuestion= new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'FormQuestion',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      itemId: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
      },
      type: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
      },
      label: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My GraphQL request :

```
query {
  getFormTemplates {
    name
    items {
      type
      question {
        label
        type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm expected is

```
{
  "data": {
    "getFormTemplates": [
      {
        "name": "Form 1",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "question",
            "question": {
              "label": "Question 1",
              "type": "shortText"

          },
          {
            "type": "rawContent"
            "question": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use normal dataType and not new GrapgQLNonNull.
ex - authorId: {type: GraphQLInt}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you David for your answer !

I've figured it out how to solve my problem using inline fragments and UnionTypes that seems to be the most adapted for this use case. Here is the code :

```
const formItemObjectType = new GraphQLUnionType({
  name: 'FormItemObject',
  types: [formItemContent, formItemQuestion],
  resolveType(parent) {
    switch (parent.type) {
      case ('question'): return formItemQuestion
      default: return formItemContent
    }
  }
})
```

and the GraphQL query using inline fragment:

```
query {
  getFormTemplates {
    name
    items {
      ...on FormItemContent {
        type,
        meta
      }
      ...on FormItemQuestion {
        type,
        meta,
        question {
           label
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd design your "level 2" items so that the "type" property corresponded to actual GraphQL types, implementing a common interface.  Also, in general, I'd design the schema so that it had actual links to neighboring items and not their identifiers.

So if every form item possibly has an associated template, you can make that be a GraphQL [interface](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces):

```graphql
interface FormItem {
  id: ID!
  template: FormTemplate
}
```

Then you can have three separate types for your three kinds of items

```graphql
# Skipping VideoItem
type ImageItem implements FormItem {
  id: ID!
  template: FormTemplate
  src: String!
}
type QuestionItem implements FormItem {
  id: ID!
  template: FormTemplate
  questions: [FormQuestion!]!
}
```

The other types you describe would be:

```graphql
type FormTemplate {
  id: ID!
  author: Author!
  name: String!
  items: [FormItem!]!
}
type FormQuestion {
  id: ID!
  question: Question
  type: String!
  label: String!
}
```

The other tricky thing is, since not all form items are questions, you have to specifically mention that you're interested in questions in your query to get the question-specific fields.  Your query might look like

```graphql
query {
  getFormTemplates {
    name
    items {
      __typename # a GraphQL builtin that gives the type of this object
      ... on Question {
        label
        type
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `... on Question` syntax is an [inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments), and you can similarly use it to pick out the fields specific to other kinds of form items.